# keyboard preferences error, setup language

Tags: keyboard

I have a Magic Keyboard A1843 and wanted to change the layout from German to UK layout (I use a MacBook Pro from 2014). I tried it with 'Setup BlueTooth keyboard' (the keyboard can be found and the BlueTooth connection is fine) but when I want to continue to set up my preferences the error 'Preference error: There was an error in Keyboard preferences' occurs.

I restarted my laptop but the error still occurs... Maybe someone could help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To change the keyboard mapping you would normally go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources, use the + button to add British to the list and use the - button to remove German from the list.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-your-mac-mchlp1406/12.0/mac/12.0